# Number format and performance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, numbers, exponent

Is there a performance difference (either in memory or speed) between either of the following options?

Option A

```
var x = 6371000;
console.log('x', x);
```

Option B

```
var x = 6371e3;
console.log('x', x);
```

Option C

```
var x = 6.371e6;
console.log('x', x);
```

All achieve the same numerical result. But A uses a long integer only. The others use exponential notation while C uses a decimal combined with an exponent.

Comment: You might want to try a site like jsPerf that lets you easily measure the performance of different JS alternatives. But I'm pretty sure that in this case, the number gets parsed when your script is first loaded, and then the performance when the script actually runs should be identical.

Comment: Javascript has only one type for all numbers that is equivalent to `double` in most other languages (64bits). `12` will be 64bits and `123456777e200` will be 64bits too.

Comment: *Is there a performance difference (either in memory or speed) between either of the following two options?* You give three options, but the answer is **no**.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. If you are creating a website then any performance difference would most likely not be measurable. If you are trying to squeeze every ounce of performance out of a system then you shouldn't be using Javascript, so the question would be moot.

Comment: Not certain what question is?

Comment: Some optimizing JavaScript JIT compilers optimize certain code hotspots on *repeated* execution by e.g. recognizing that your first number literal fits into a 32-bit integer and subsequently performing integer arithmetic instead of more expensive floating point arithmetic. Whether this speeds up console logging... I don't think so. The optimized version probably requires more memory due to hot-swapping out the unoptimized for the optimized code.